# Neo4j.rb returns models with incorrect class for nodes with multiple labels

Tags: neo4j.rb

I have two ActiveNode models:

```
class Company
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end
```

and

```
class Entity
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end
```

They correspond to the labels "Entity" and "Company", which are attached to the same node. So, a node and be an entity and a company.

In my console, when I attempt the following query:

```
Entity.where(entity_id: 1).first
```

It returns a Company object:

```
#<Company uuid: entity_id: 1>
```

I don't want that. If I ask for an entity, I want an entity returned. The Entity model have different methods defined than the Company model. Is there anyway I can enforce the correct behavior? It seems pretty pretty counter intuitive that it behaves in this way.

I am using neo4j 3.0 and neo4j.rb 7.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good point.  If both labels could be matched, it should use the one for the class which was used to do the find.

I'm curious about your modeling, though.  Can a `Company` node ever not be an `Entity` or vice versa?  Or is, for example, a `Company` always a kind of an `Entity`?  If so, you might want to use inheritence:

```
class Entity
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end

class Company < Entity
  # No need to include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end
```

But it's partially a question of if it makes sense for `Company` nodes to inherit the behavior/logic of `Entity`

Comment: Yes, that works! And it does make sense, for my data. But I think the behavior is illogical anyway, but glad there is a workaround.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I definitely want to hear if there's some use-case that we're missing.  Thanks for the feedback!